# Can't pickle <class 'pywintypes.datetime'>: attribute lookup datetime on pywintypes failed

Tags: python-3.5

I am using python 3.5 (32bit), win10-64bit, OpenOPC, and I have downloaded pywin32 build 64bit. I have run the following python code:

```
import OpenOPC
import time
opc=OpenOPC.client()

opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1')

tags =['Random.Int4','Random.Real4']

while True:

   try:

       value = opc.read(tags,group='Group0',update=1)

       print (value)

   except OpenOPC.TimeoutError:

       print ("TimeoutError occured")


   time.sleep(5)
```

but I always get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 241, in _feed
>       obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
>       cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
>   _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup datetime on pywintypes failed.

Answer (score 10):

I have found a solution:

```
import OpenOPC
import time

import pywintypes

pywintypes.datetime = pywintypes.TimeType

opc=OpenOPC.client()

opc.servers()

opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1')
tags =['Random.Int1','Random.Real4','Random.Int2','Random.Real8']
while True:
   try:
       value = opc.read(tags,group='Group0',update=1)
       print (value)
   except OpenOPC.TimeoutError:
       print ("TimeoutError occured")

   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Excellent! Works with Python 3.9. @HosnyAbbas you can accept your own answer as it works. Thank you.

Comment: That...would have taken a very long time for me to figure out. Thank you for posting the solution!